# passing arguments and getting count in cells in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code where the count of a cell gets updated based on a search from a specific column, specific text and specific worksheet.

```
Sub WBR()
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                'no of tickets processed - summary
[AE43] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", _
                      .Range("G:G"), "<>Not Tested", _
                      .Range("U:U"), "Item")
 End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                'not tested tickets - summary
[AE44] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Not Tested")
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                'Tickets moved back- outdated OS and App Versions - summary
[AE45] = wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Outdated App Version") + wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Outdated OS")
End With
```

How do I pass argument such that when it meets the condition, the count should be updated in the designated cell?

Comment: please make an example

Comment: Currently thecodes just goes to the worksheet mentioned and scans a column for a specific string and if it matches, it will give the total count of the matched row in the designated cell. So I need to apply the same code to 30+ cells to perform this task (with diff strings as the search conditions in diff sheets). If the above code can be converted into hash with arguments (arguments being the sheet name, text to search,range to place the count, col to search) and when the arguments (the string here) meets the condition, the count should be updated in the designated cell.

Comment: Just use variables instead of constants such as `"TT"` and `"Not Tested"` and `"G:G"`.  Set those variables however you like (e.g. by looking up a range in Excel, or from an array created in VBA, or by an `InputBox`, or by a Form, or by whatever other method you think of).

Comment: I dont want an input box here. Can you pl give a small example by using an array? I could follow the same to implement what I think. @YowE3K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample** code using an array to store all your constants:

```
Sub WBR()
    Dim Count1Criteria As Variant
    Dim Count3Criteria As Variant
    Dim test As Variant
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    Count1Criteria = Array(Array("AE44", "TT", "G:G", "Not Tested"), _
                           Array("AF44", "TT", "U:U", "Item"))

    Count3Criteria = Array(Array("AE43", "TT", "I:I", "<>Duplicate TT", _
                                               "G:G", "<>Not Tested", _
                                               "U:U", "Item"), _
                           Array("AF43", "TT", "I:I", "<>Duplicate TT", _
                                               "G:G", "<>Not Tested", _
                                               "U:U", "Item"))


    For Each test In Count1Criteria
        With Worksheets(test(1))
            Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.Range(test(2)), test(3))
        End With
    Next                                   
    For Each test In Count3Criteria
        With Worksheets(test(1))
            Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.Range(test(2)), test(3), _
                                         .Range(test(4)), test(5), _
                                         .Range(test(6)), test(7))
        End With
    Next                                   
End Sub
```

This won't handle all your cases - you have some where you need to add two (or more) results together - but it should give an idea of how to make the code less "repetitive".

Comment: will try this out..but what does "test" here stands for? test(0), test(1) etc? ALso, is there a way yo "hash" the arguments using "dictionary" ?

Comment: @walterwhile - (a) `test` is just a variable name.  I was going to use `x` but decided that that wasn't very meaningful, so I went for `test` to signify each "test" being performed.  Maybe rename it to `countToBePerformed`?  Or anything else you like.  (b) You could use a dictionary for the values if you liked - I used an array because that's what you asked me to provide sample code for.

Comment: Got it!! If "dictionary" is sued..will it be better than array? If I have to use dictionary in this code what changes should I make?

Comment: @walterwhile - It is very hard to tell what is the "best" method to use - it all depends on why you are trying to parameterise it.  To reduce code size? To make it look neater?  To make it easier to allow end-users to modify the code? (If so, do they want to change code or just a "table" in Excel?)  To be honest, I'm not sure why you are even using VBA rather than just using Excel formulas, but I guess this is just one part of some bigger application.

Comment: -I'm just looking it to reduce the duplication of code usage. To reduce the number of lines to be coded. Yes I agree, using formulas will be far more easier, but I want it to be like an automation so i'm using vba

Comment: I just worked out the code and it is pretty cool. But the catch here is  - for example: In COunt3Criteria, the text to be searched will always not be the same and also the cell no..so again I need to rewrite code again for different cells and search text..Is there a way once we give the cells number and search keyword for a specific sheet, it should loop through the code and count the values if it meets the condition?

Comment: @walterwhile - I just reused the same search criteria for both tests in Count3Criteria because I assumed you would realise that you could enter whatever criteria you wanted.  (I **did** change the destination cell in the two cases.)  At some stage, you need to type in the criteria you want to use for each destination cell.  Where/how you do it is up to you - you can use arrays, dictionaries, ranges in Excel, hardcoded code, even an external file that you read the values from, whatever you think is best.

Comment: I was playing around with the code till now and its really good...And BTW can you give the same sample in the form of dictionaries?

Comment: @walterwhile - No, while I know a Dictionary **could** be used, I don't have sufficient experience in using them for this purpose.  It would possibly take me just as long to learn as it would take you and, even after I had read up on them, I would be scared that any example I created would be potentially misleading.

Comment: something just struck me..not sure whether it's feaisble...is it possible to store all the cells to be updated in a single array and store all the sheet names in another array, similarly for other changing variable..then use these arrays to run check for the condition in a specific sheet and if it matches, the count would be updated on the destination cell..anything along this line? probably looping through? this might stupid so please excuse me if its not possible

Comment: @walterwhile - yes, it's certainly possible to use different arrays for the different parts (destination, sheet, range, criteria) needed for your `CountIfs`.  But you will still have to type in the same amount of information, unless you can find out some way to associate certain positions in the sheet array (for instance) with certain positions in the destination array (for instance).